# How to show once a line on which same word appears in multiple?

Tags: notepad++

Assume the text file contains the lines below.

Line 1 : Job description
Line 2 : Requires programming languages : C, C++, JAVA and python.
Line 3 : Candidate must have good knowledge about embedded system.
Line 4 : Must have experience in developing device driver. Must have skill to read H/W schematic.
Line 5 : Hope for you to apply this position.

When I search "must", the result is as follow. Line 4 appears twice because it has must 2 times. But I want to see it only once.

Search "must" (3 hits in 1 file)
  new 3 (3 hits)
    Line 3: Candidate **must** have good knowledge about embedded system.
    Line 4: **Must** have experience in developing device driver. Must have skill to read H/W schematic.
    Line 4: Must have experience in developing device driver. **Must** have skill to read H/W schematic.

Could you help me?

Comment: how did you search? used any api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [negative look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

Find what: `must(?!.*?must)`

This will find `must` only if it is not followed by another `must`