# With notepad++, if "Find All" strings match multiple times in 1 line, output shows duplicated lines

Tags: grep, notepad++, text-editor

I would like to know how to prevent notepad++ to output duplicated lines when I execute Find All.

Here is sample text file.

```
aaa aaa
bbb bbb
ccc ccc
```

I put "aaa" as search strings and click "Find All in Current Document".
Then output will be like this. Line 1 appears 2 times because strings "aaa" matched 2 times in line 1.

```
Search "aaa" (2 hits in 1 file)
  new 2 (2 hits)
    Line 1: aaa aaa
    Line 1: aaa aaa
```

It is bothering to remove duplicated lines later. Is there any good method to prevent duplicated lines?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show once a line on which same word appears in multiple?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742835/how-to-show-once-a-line-on-which-same-word-appears-in-multiple)

Comment: You could do a regular expression search for `aaa.*` .

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of a way to make the "Find result" window remove "duplicate lines". They originate from the multiple hits on the same line.

To stop the dupes from appearing is to make sure you only find the last occurrence of the string on a line.

To do this, you need to use a regex in the following form:

```
(\Qaa.a\E)(?!.*\1)
```

where `<YOUR_VALUE>` is `aaa`. The `\Q` and `\E` operators are necessary to make the regex engine treat all chars between them as literal characters. The `(...)` will capture the search string into Group 1 and the `(?!.*\1)` negative lookahead will fail all matches that are followed with the same search string on the line (as `.*` matches any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols).

[image]